# Proof by natural deduction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I'm new to sentential logic / metalogic. Where should I start to learn how to do proof by natural deduction. Without the use of any aditional rules, how would you go about proving that the following sentence is a sentence-logical truth?

LaTeX: \begin{array}{l}
p \land q\\
\hline
\neg(p \to \neg q)
\end{array}

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page, can you say which rules you can use?

Comment: You haven't given us any rules at all ... let alone any additional rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the set of rules I have for natural deduction, I would go about it like this:

First, we can use elimination of conjunction ($E\wedge$) on $p \wedge q,$ yielding $p$ and $q$.

Now, assume $p \to \neg q.$ By elimination of implication ($E\to$) we have that $p$ and $p \to \neg q$ yields $\neg q$. Now we can use elimination of negation ($E\neg$) to show that $q$ and $\neg q$ yield a contradiction, $\bot$.

Now because $p \to \neg q$ yields a contradiction, we can use introduction of negation ($I\neg$) yielding $\neg(p \to \neg q)$, and we're done.

If you're allowed to use some heavier machinery, then you can just go about it using DeMorgan's law as the other answer has pointed out.